# Grammar matching regex character classes, trailing dash

Tags: parsing, grammar, bnf, lalr

I'm writing my own LALR(1) parser-generator so I'm not sure if I have an issue with my parser-generator or my grammar.

I'm trying to generate a parser for regexes.
I have the following rules for character classes (slightly simplified):

```
LBRACKET: "[" // the [ character
RBRACKET: "]"
DASH: "-"
CHAR: [^[\]] // everything except square brackets

class ::= LBRACKET class_contents RBRACKET

class_contents ::= class_element | class_element class_contents

class_element ::= literal | literal DASH literal

literal ::= DASH | CHAR
```

I can match regexes such as `[a-bc-d]`, but I cannot match `[a-bc-de-]` which should correspond to a rule matching the characters `a, b, c, d, e, -`.

It seems that upon seeing the tokens `e` (type `literal`) and `-` (type `DASH`), the parser tries to match the rule `literal DASH literal`.
After seeing `]` (type `RBRACKET`), it needs to realize it started the wrong production.

Is this a case where the parser needs 2 lookahead tokens, so LALR(1) is insufficient?
In this case, is there a way to rewrite the grammar so that it works?
Or is this grammar valid for matching `[a-bc-de-]` and I should look for a bug in my parser-generator?

Comment: What parser are you using? If you wrote it, what did you base it on? And what lexer are you using? It looks like an issue of a shift-reduce collision.

Comment: @Erez I'm using my own lexer. Both are based off the dragon book and some links I found on the internet, mainly https://web.cs.dal.ca/~sjackson/lalr1.html . I also suspected a shift-reduce collision, but was wondering if there was a way to fix the grammar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out, your grammar is ambiguous. While it is sometimes possible to resolve ambiguities (which show up as shift/reduce conflicts) using standard heuristics -- "prefer shift to reduce", for example -- this technique is not entirely general, and it is not always easy to understand the consequences of the resolution.

Practical LALR generators do have resolution algorithms, typically based on operator precedence declarations with a fallback to the default algorithms (prefer shift, if there isn't a shift, prefer the first reduction in the grammar). These technique can simplify grammar writing, and sometimes make the grammar more readable and faster to parse. But once you get out of the comfort zone for automatic parser conflict resolution, the shine begins to wear off a bit.

It is not difficult to create an unambiguous grammar, particularly if you start with a precise definition of what allowable sentences are. Here, I'm going to use a simplified version of the Posix standard for regex character classes, in order to focus on the precise issue of allowing the trailing dash as a character. Removed from the standard:

- collation elements (`[.ä.]`)
- equivalence classes (`[=œ=]`)
- standard named character classes (`[:alpha:]`)
- negated classes (`[^…]`)

According to [Posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09), a `-` in a character class is treated as though it were an ordinary character "if it occurs first (after an initial `^`, if any) or last in the list, or as an ending range point in a range expression."  (Also, empty character classes are not allowed; if a `]` is the first character in the class, it too is treated as an ordinary character.) Below, I don't (yet) implement the first of these three criteria (first in the list), concentrating on the other two. That allows for a very simple grammar, similar to the one provided by Michael Dyck:

```
/* I use bison syntax in order to be able to easily test the grammars */
class   : '[' contents ']'   /* See Note 1 */
contents: '-'
        | unit
        | unit contents
unit    : CHAR
        | CHAR '-' CHAR      /* See Note 2 */
        | CHAR '-' '-'
```

As with Michael's grammar, this grammar is unambiguous but LALR(2), which makes it theoretically interesting but practically almost useless since there are no commonly available LALR(2) parser generators. You could parse it with a GLR or Early parser, but it is also possible to mechanically transform an (LA)LR(k) grammar into an (LA)LR(1) grammar [Note 3]. (Michael alludes to this construction, too.)

I've mentioned this fact in a number of SO answers, but this grammar is actually simple enough to make it possible to do the transform by hand, which might make it slightly easier to understand.

The transformation is simple enough. To reduce LR(k) to LR(1), we simply shift every reduction to the right by `k-1` tokens. To do that, for each grammar symbol `V` (both terminals and non-terminals) we create all possible "delayed" grammar symbols. Each such symbol has the form `firstVfollow`, where `first` and `follow` are sequences of length `k-1` from the `FIRSTk−1` and `FOLLOWk−1` sets of `V` [Note 3]. The new symbol `firstVfollow` represents an instance of `V` which appeared k−1 tokens earlier in the input stream, but which can be reduced at this point because there is now enough information to decide.

Obviously, this represents an enormous blow-up in the size of the grammar, although it is more or less manageable for simple grammars with `k = 2`. In practice, it would be just as manageable to construct the (LA)LR(k) parser. Also, the transformed grammar is far from readable, which is a key feature of grammar-based parser generation. (That wouldn't matter if the transformation were done in the background by a computer program, of course.) But the construction does serve as a proof that every (LA)LR(k) grammar has an equivalent (LA)LR(1) grammar.

The full construction also shows how to undo the transformation during the construction of the parse tree. I haven't seen a description of how to transform semantic actions, but it's not very difficult with yacc/bison. What's needed is to give every (transformed) symbol two attributes (or, in bisonic terms, a `struct` consisting of two values): one represents the semantic value of the (delayed) symbol being reduced, and the other represents the semantic value of the token which was just shifted.

In a symbol of the form `firstVfollow`, the reduce value is the semantic value of `V`, while the delayed token value is the semantic value of the last token in `follow`. Yacc/bison implement a rarely-used extension to the `$i` syntax which allows the semantic action to refer to semantic values which occur earlier in the value stack by using values of `i` less than 1. Using this mechanism, the token value corresponding to the symbol `$i` will be found at `$(i &minus; (k&minus;1))`. (Since `i` must be a constant, you have to do the subtraction yourself when writing the rule.)

In the example that follows, I don't use reduction values at all; instead, the reduction just prints the value of the reduction. Semantic value references like `$0` are the result of applying the above formula. (In this case, `k-1` is 1, so `$0` refers to the token value of the symbol at position 1 in the right-hand side.)

With that, here's a complete program which you can use to test the grammar:

```
$ cat charclass.y
%token CHAR
%code {
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int yylex(void) {
  int c;
  do c = getchar(); while (c != '\n' && isspace(c));
  yylval = c;
  switch (c) {
    case EOF: return 0;
    case '\n': case '-': case '[': case ']': return c;
    default: return CHAR;
  }
}
void yyerror(const char* msg) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
}
}

%%
input: %empty
     | input class '\n'
     | input '\n'
     | error '\n' { yyerrok; }

/* Original untransformed grammar, for reference */
class: '[' contents ']'
contents: '-' | unit | unit contents
unit    : CHAR | CHAR '-' CHAR | CHAR '-' '-'
*/

class              : '[' OPEN-class-epsi                          { fputc('\n', stderr); }
OPEN-class-epsi    : OPEN-OPEN-DASH DASH-contents-CLOS CLOS-CLOS-epsi
                   | OPEN-OPEN-CHAR CHAR-contents-CLOS CLOS-CLOS-epsi
DASH-contents-CLOS : DASH-DASH-CLOS                               { fprintf(stderr, "CHR(%c) ", $0); }
CHAR-contents-CLOS : CHAR-unit-CLOS
                   | CHAR-unit-DASH DASH-contents-CLOS
                   | CHAR-unit-CHAR CHAR-contents-CLOS
CHAR-unit-CLOS     : CHAR-CHAR-CLOS                               { fprintf(stderr, "CHR(%c) ", $0); }
                   | CHAR-CHAR-DASH DASH-DASH-CHAR CHAR-CHAR-CLOS { fprintf(stderr, "RNG(%c-%c) ", $0, $2); }
                   | CHAR-CHAR-DASH DASH-DASH-DASH DASH-DASH-CLOS { fprintf(stderr, "RNG(%c-%c) ", $0, $2); }
CHAR-unit-DASH     : CHAR-CHAR-DASH                               { $$ = $1; fprintf(stderr, "CHR(%c) ", $0); }
                   | CHAR-CHAR-DASH DASH-DASH-CHAR CHAR-CHAR-DASH { $$ = $3; fprintf(stderr, "RNG(%c-%c) ", $0, $2); }
                   | CHAR-CHAR-DASH DASH-DASH-DASH DASH-DASH-DASH { $$ = $3; fprintf(stderr, "RNG(%c-%c) ", $0, $2); }
CHAR-unit-CHAR     : CHAR-CHAR-CHAR                               { $$ = $1; fprintf(stderr, "CHR(%c) ", $0); }
                   | CHAR-CHAR-DASH DASH-DASH-CHAR CHAR-CHAR-CHAR { $$ = $3; fprintf(stderr, "RNG(%c-%c) ", $0, $2); }
                   | CHAR-CHAR-DASH DASH-DASH-DASH DASH-DASH-CHAR { $$ = $3; fprintf(stderr, "RNG(%c-%c) ", $0, $2); }
CLOS-CLOS-epsi     : %empty
CHAR-CHAR-CHAR     : CHAR
CHAR-CHAR-CLOS     : ']'
CHAR-CHAR-DASH     : '-'
DASH-DASH-CHAR     : CHAR
DASH-DASH-CLOS     : ']'
DASH-DASH-DASH     : '-'
OPEN-OPEN-DASH     : '-'
OPEN-OPEN-CHAR     : CHAR

%%
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
#if YYDEBUG
  if (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "-d") == 0) yydebug = 1;
#endif
  return yyparse();
}
```

Here's a short sample run:

```
$ bison -t -o charclass.c charclass.y && gcc -Wall -std=c11 -o charclass -ggdb charclass.c
$ ./charclass
[abc]
CHR(a) CHR(b) CHR(c) 
[a-bc]
RNG(a-b) CHR(c) 
[ab-c]
CHR(a) RNG(b-c) 
[ab-]
CHR(a) CHR(b) CHR(-) 
[a-b-]
RNG(a-b) CHR(-) 
[a--]
RNG(a--) 
[a---]
RNG(a--) CHR(-) 
[a-b-c]
RNG(a-b) syntax error
```

Studying the bison trace might or might not help. FWIW, here's one example:

```
$ ./charclass -d <<< '[a-b-]'
Starting parse
Entering state 0
Reading a token: Next token is token '[' ()
Reducing stack by rule 1 (line 23):
-> $$ = nterm input ()
Stack now 0
Entering state 2
Next token is token '[' ()
Shifting token '[' ()
Entering state 6
Reading a token: Next token is token CHAR ()
Shifting token CHAR ()
Entering state 8
Reducing stack by rule 29 (line 58):
   $1 = token CHAR ()
-> $$ = nterm OPEN-OPEN-CHAR ()
Stack now 0 2 6
Entering state 12
Reading a token: Next token is token '-' ()
Shifting token '-' ()
Entering state 19
Reducing stack by rule 24 (line 53):
   $1 = token '-' ()
-> $$ = nterm CHAR-CHAR-DASH ()
Stack now 0 2 6 12
Entering state 26
Reading a token: Next token is token CHAR ()
Shifting token CHAR ()
Entering state 31
Reducing stack by rule 25 (line 54):
   $1 = token CHAR ()
-> $$ = nterm DASH-DASH-CHAR ()
Stack now 0 2 6 12 26
Entering state 33
Reading a token: Next token is token '-' ()
Shifting token '-' ()
Entering state 19
Reducing stack by rule 24 (line 53):
   $1 = token '-' ()
-> $$ = nterm CHAR-CHAR-DASH ()
Stack now 0 2 6 12 26 33
Entering state 37
Reducing stack by rule 16 (line 45):
   $1 = nterm CHAR-CHAR-DASH ()
   $2 = nterm DASH-DASH-CHAR ()
   $3 = nterm CHAR-CHAR-DASH ()
RNG(a-b) -> $$ = nterm CHAR-unit-DASH ()
Stack now 0 2 6 12
Entering state 22
Reading a token: Next token is token ']' ()
Shifting token ']' ()
Entering state 14
Reducing stack by rule 26 (line 55):
   $1 = token ']' ()
-> $$ = nterm DASH-DASH-CLOS ()
Stack now 0 2 6 12 22
Entering state 16
Reducing stack by rule 8 (line 37):
   $1 = nterm DASH-DASH-CLOS ()
CHR(-) -> $$ = nterm DASH-contents-CLOS ()
Stack now 0 2 6 12 22
Entering state 29
Reducing stack by rule 10 (line 39):
   $1 = nterm CHAR-unit-DASH ()
   $2 = nterm DASH-contents-CLOS ()
-> $$ = nterm CHAR-contents-CLOS ()
Stack now 0 2 6 12
Entering state 20
Reducing stack by rule 21 (line 50):
-> $$ = nterm CLOS-CLOS-epsi ()
Stack now 0 2 6 12 20
Entering state 28
Reducing stack by rule 7 (line 36):
   $1 = nterm OPEN-OPEN-CHAR ()
   $2 = nterm CHAR-contents-CLOS ()
   $3 = nterm CLOS-CLOS-epsi ()
-> $$ = nterm OPEN-class-epsi ()
Stack now 0 2 6
Entering state 10
Reducing stack by rule 5 (line 34):
   $1 = token '[' ()
   $2 = nterm OPEN-class-epsi ()

-> $$ = nterm class ()
Stack now 0 2
Entering state 7
Reading a token: Next token is token '\n' ()
Shifting token '\n' ()
Entering state 13
Reducing stack by rule 2 (line 24):
   $1 = nterm input ()
   $2 = nterm class ()
   $3 = token '\n' ()
-> $$ = nterm input ()
Stack now 0
Entering state 2
Reading a token: Now at end of input.
Shifting token $end ()
Entering state 4
Stack now 0 2 4
Cleanup: popping token $end ()
Cleanup: popping nterm input ()
```

I have relied on the description of the algorithm in section 6.7 of *Parsing Theory* by S. Sippu and E: Soisalon-Soininen (Springer-Verlag, 1988) which should be available in any good academic library.

#### Notes:

1. bison, like many parser generators, lets you write single-character tokens with single quotes, which makes the grammar a bit more readable, IMHO.
2. In order to simplify the following step, I avoided defining

   any: CHAR | '-'

   which could have been used to allow `-` as the "ending range point" (as in `%--`).  (`unit: CHAR '-' any`). Instead, I wrote two `unit` rules,  effectively expanding the `any` production above.
3. The transformation described below transforms an LR(k) grammar into an LR(1) grammar, or an LALR(k) grammar into an LALR(1) grammar. I use `(LA)LR(k)` as short-hand to represent these two cases; that's imprecise because the transformation also transforms an SLR(k) grammar into an SLR(1) grammar.
4. In the example here `k-1` is 1 and there are no epsilon productions, so we can simply use the `FIRST` set for the grammar symbol. But in the general case, it is possible that a given symbol `V` has a derivation which is shorter than `k-1`. A more precise formulation is that `follow` is an element in `FOLLOWk−1(V)` and `first` is an element in `FIRSTk−1(V # follow)`, using `#` as the concatenation operator.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer! It took me a while to think about it. To reduce LR(k) to LR(1), do you create a grammar symbol <code><sub>first</sub>V<sub>follow</sub></code> for every pair of $k - 1$-length sequences from $\text{First}_{k - 1}$ and $\text{Follow}_{k - 1}$?

Comment: @raekye: not quite all in some cases; you don't need the ones which are impossible. (First and follow can overlap; consider, for example, a marker whose RHS is empty.). But basically, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, LALR(1) is insufficient. A LALR(1) parser-generator should be complaining about a shift-reduce conflict in the production:

```
class_element ::= literal | literal DASH literal
```

After shifting a `literal`, you go to a state whose kernel is the two items:

```
class_element ::= literal .
class_element ::= literal . DASH literal
```

which call for a reduce action and a shift action respectively, and this cannot be resolved by 1 symbol of lookahead, because the follow set for the reduce action includes DASH.

And 2 tokens of lookahead won't work either. In fact, this grammar isn't LALR(k) for any k, because it's ambiguous: `class_contents` can derive `literal DASH literal` in 2 ways (either as three `class_elements` or as one).

---

> In this case, is there a way to rewrite the grammar so that it works?

(Sorry, missed that part of the original question.)

It's possible to make an unambiguous grammar for this language. You'll almost certainly have to drop the `literal ::= DASH` production. And you'll probably need/want to restrict "literal DASH" to the end of the class. E.g., I think this would do it:

```
class_contents ::= DASH | class_element | class_element class_contents

class_element ::= literal | literal DASH literal

literal ::= CHAR
```

(You could equivalently restrict "literal DASH" to the *start* of the class. Allowing both would be possible, but probably not as simple.)

Although unambiguous, this grammar is still not LALR(1): it has the same shift-reduce problem as the original. However, I think it's LALR(2).

If you really want LALR(1), there's a theoretical result that says any LALR(k) grammar can be converted to an equivalent LALR(1) grammar. But I'm not sure what the result would look like.

---

Note that the question "Is LALR(1) sufficient?" might mean:

> "Can a LALR(1) parser(-generator) handle this grammar?"

or

> "Is there a LALR(1) grammar that can express this language?"

I addressed both questions, in that order, but should have been clearer about the distinction.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this grammar? Because there is no ambiguity in how the regex character class "should" be parsed (e.g. interpreting it as a human), and the trailing dash is allowed in most regex libraries I've seen. `literal DASH literal` should always be one `class_element`, but if there is `literal DASH (not literal, i.e right square bracket)` it should be 2 `class_element`s

Comment: I expanded my answer to talk about fixing the grammar.

Comment: Actually this seems to not handle cases such as `[--?]`, which would be a character class from `-` to `?`

Comment: @Raekye: Posix character classes can use `-` as the end of their range, but not the beginning, with the exception that `-` and `]` are treated as though they were ordinary characters if they are at the very beginning of the regex. Michael's grammar doesn't handle either of those cases, but they're easy to add.

Comment: @MichaelDyck: In case you're interested, I did the LALR(2)->LALR(1) transformation by hand and put it into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

LALR(1) should be okay for this. You just need to rewrite `class_element` as left-recursion, which is usually preferable in LALR(1)

```
class: LBRACKET class_contents RBRACKET
class_contents: class_element | class_element class_contents
class_element: literal | class_element DASH literal
literal: DASH | CHAR
```

I tested this grammar on the following inputs, and it seems to work well:

```
[a-bc-de-]
[a-bc-de]
[-a-bc-de]
[-]
```

Comment: Would this also parse `[a-b-c]` as `(class_element (class_element a - b) - c)`? That's not ideal but I suppose it can be worked with. Did you try this with bison or what did you use? I would like to play around with it, as I'm having issues with my own parser

Comment: I used my own parser, lark: https://github.com/lark-parser/lark/

 Install it with `pip install lark-parser`, And here's the code to use it: https://pastebin.com/fBtVfMFw

Comment: Amazing! I was just looking at the lark parser and your profile and wondering if you worked on it. I'm trying to understand your code. May I ask, am I correct that the bulk of the lalr parser generator is in `grammar.py`, `parsers/grammar_analysis.py`, `parsers/lalr_analysis.py`, and `parsers/lalr_parser.py`? There doesn't appear to be much code (which is amazing, as most other parser-generators I've read seem quite convoluted). If you could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated. I'm trying to build my own to learn but to be honest I don't understand much yet

Comment: Yes, you're right. Most parser-generators are written somewhat incoherently in my humble opinion. `lalr_parser.py` is the actual parser, that uses the generated parse table. `grammar.py` and `grammar_analysis.py` are mostly the setup for generating the table, and `lalr_analysis.py` does, of course, the lalr-specific analysis, including shift-reduce resolution.

LALR(1) is a very simple algorithm, once you get it. It's just rarely explained well, imho. Feel free to pop in the gitter chat (link in the lark page) and ask questions there

Comment: As with the original grammar, this grammar can't be LALR(1), because it's ambiguous: `class_contents` derives `literal DASH literal` in two different ways. (Of course, some parser generators accept ambiguous grammars and choose to resolve the conflicts somehow.)

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers, but in the end accepted Michael's since it provides more information for future readers. I upvoted both answers. I would encourage anyone reading this to look at the lark project though!

Comment: But his comment is incorrect, and I'm not saying this out of a grudge. He declares in the first line that "LALR(1) is insufficient", but I have proven that it's possible with LALR(1), vanilla and without any tricks, unless you consider industry standard shift-reduce resolution as "not true LALR". Even after he suggests a fix, he declares "Although unambiguous, this grammar is still not LALR(1)". I worry that accepting his answer will just spread misinformation about LALR(1) is really capable of.

Comment: erez: Your grammar, in addition to being ambiguous, is incorrect since it accepts `a-b-c`. @michael's (second) grammar is unambiguous and correct (more or less, depending on what exact character class syntax you want to implement) but it won't correctly parse with "industry-standard" conflict resolution.

Comment: @rici Fair enough. I was looking at it from an engineering standpoint, where finding a solution is more important than precisely classifying the problem. But I accept that others might have different priorities.